# .bat file to find and delete part of a string using wildcards

Tags: javascript, batch-file

I have a bunch of DIVs that have too much information in them. I want to search in the text file for the DIVs and then delete the back half of the DIV.

The thing is the DIVs are all unique (but start with the same thing) and the endings are all unique.

Here is an example;

```
 @echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set string=<div id="zip?????">              
 set "find=<div id="zip?????*">"             
 call set delete=%%string:!find!=%%
 call set string=%%string:!delete!=%%
 echo %string%
```

This is what the DIV looks like:
        **div id="zip75001 Addison 3296129 -9683751">**
This is what I want it to look like:
        **div id="zip75001">**

All of the numbers after "ZIP" IN "ZIP ID" e.g. id="zip#####" will be unique (I want to keep those) and everything after the zip code e.g.  Addison 3296129 -9683751 (space, city name, Lat and Long) I want to delete. Note these are all unique too.

Comment: You got me curious, why would you use a batch file for this ?

Comment: I have a lot of replacement text in one file that all have variables. The core is the same div id="zip12345 Richmond 35.1234 -96.12534"> and I only want to keep div id="zip12345" <---Note the 12345 will be different in every div so I want to keep div id="zip*****"> and delete "Richmond 35.1234 -96.12534" which will also be different in every div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use !, but you must have the ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION switch set.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set word=table
set str="jump over the chair"
set str=%str:chair=!word!%
```

Or You can use the following little trick:

```
set word=table
set str="jump over the chair"
call set str=%%str:chair=%word%%%
echo %str%
```

The call there causes another layer of variable expansion, making it necessary to quote the original % signs but it all works out in the end.